# How to set QWidget width?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

How to set `QWidget` width? I know `setGeometry(QRect& rect)` function to do that, but in that case I should use `geometry()` function to get former parameters of my `QWidget`, then I should increment the width and use setGeometry(..). Is there any direct way to that, say:

```
QWidget aa;
aa.setWidth(165); //something like this?
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[`resize()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop) might be better to use.

Example usage:

```
widget->resize(165, widget->height());
```

Comment: If content is larger than the widget, widget won't resize. In that case put all content on top of a QScrollarea. Then It'll resize and you can see the scrolling bars.

Answer (score 15):

```
widget->resize(165, widget->height());
```

Answer (score 6):

[QWidget reference.](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html)

Try examining all available **"yyysize"** methods *(because there are different sizing policies for Qt widgets and you might need something special).*

Basically, yes, it's `resize(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

If the width won't change afterwards, you can use [`setFixedWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth):

```
widget->setFixedWidth(165);
```

Similarly, to change the height without changing the width, there is [`setFixedHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight).

Comment: Never use fixed width! For varius reselutions it will not work.

Comment: And you can't change your size in the future. Bad answer.